# how to make dynamic css cards

Tags: html, css

```html
<div id="cards">
                <div class="mbhs">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="content/MBHS.jpg" alt="MBHS">
                    </div>
                    <div class="top">
                        Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="exp">
                        Example text here
                    </div>
                    <div class="comp">
                        Example text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ominous">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="content/ominous.jpg" alt="Ominous">
                    </div>
                    <div class="top">
                        Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="exp">
                        Example text here
                    </div>
                    <div class="comp">
                        Example text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```css
#cards {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


#cards > * {
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#cards > * > .image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: MaxSize;
    max-height: MaxSize;
}

#cards > * > .top {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: clamp(2em, 2vw, 4em);
}

#cards > * > .comp {
    color: #6CACE4;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#cards > * > .exp {
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #C4C4C4;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I'm attempting to make these two (and soon to be more) cards fluidly expand so both of them evenly fill up the content area in the middle of the screen.

[image: example showing what it should look like]

I'm able to get this code working on the HTML preview extension on vsc but not on the live server. On the live server the images just resize to their default size and ignore the limits.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your css a little bit, and add two more items into your flexbox. Maybe this is your intended layout? Hope this help!

```css
#cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#cards>* {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.image {}

.top {
  padding-block: 10px;
  font-size: clamp(2em, 2vw, 4em);
}

.comp {
  color: #6CACE4;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.exp {
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: left;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="mbhs">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" alt="MBHS" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="exp">
      Example text here
    </div>
    <div class="comp">
      Example text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ominous">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" alt="Ominous" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="exp">
      Example text here
    </div>
    <div class="comp">
      Example text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mbhs">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" alt="MBHS" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="exp">
      Example text here
    </div>
    <div class="comp">
      Example text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mbhs">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" alt="MBHS" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="exp">
      Example text here
    </div>
    <div class="comp">
      Example text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```